# How many different ways can positions be filled out with overlapping candidates?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, additive-combinatorics

Suppose I am trying to fill up positions $A,B,C$ with candidates $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ and each candidate can only be in one position at most. Each position has a set of candidates who have applied, for example we can say that the candidates for each position are given as follows
$$
\begin{align}
Can(A)&=\{1,2,3,4\} \\
Can(B)&=\{2,3,4,5\} \\
Can(C)&=\{3,4,5,6\} 
\end{align}
$$

Clearly we can't just $4^3$ because the intersection of the positions are non-empty. Obviously, this little toy example can be brute forced pretty easily or proved by cases that you grind out, but I wanted to know if there was a better formula for this that generalized for larger cases?

Comment: The question of whether or not it is even possible to select such candidates in the first place without repetition is covered by [Hall's Marriage Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall%27s_marriage_theorem).  I do not know off the top of my head any results in counting the number of suitable matchings.

Comment: Possibly related: [Exact cover](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_cover)

Comment: @JMoravitz The sets I will be working with (League of Legends champions lol) are sufficiently large and structured so that a solution will be guaranteed so that isn't an issue for this problem

Comment: In the event there are exactly as many categories as there are candidates, you can construct a zero-one adjacency matrix and count the number of possibilities by computing the [permanent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permanent_(mathematics)) of the matrix (*not to be confused with the determinant of the matrix*).  In the event of more candidates than categories, as suggested [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/19275/number-of-matchings-in-a-bipartite) you can create enough extra number of "positions" where these final positions can be filled by any candidate, and adjust the count.

Comment: Admittedly, this is going to be effectively the same as brute forcing the count (*though at least done so in an organized way*) and effectively looks at each possible pattern of having selected candidates for each position, incrementing the overall count by 1 for each valid arrangement (*multiple times in the case you had to artificially increase the number of positions, which you later divide out to correct*), and this computation will be rather costly in terms of complexity.

Comment: Given the context (*MOBA games and relatively low team sizes compared to rosters*) I would think it would be far easier to just directly brute force without the use of artificially increasing the number of positions to later divide.

Comment: You can find many references to this problem by typing *number of matchings in a bipartite graph* into your favorite search engine.

Comment: I see, it seems that the algorithm for bipartite matching is exponential and for my input size $n=167$ that might be unfeasible. Perhaps heuristics and brute for is the way to go here